# Function is not showing up in the OnClick editor

Tags: unity

I'm just a beginner and I am currently having problems with the OnClick editor. I already drag and dropped my script to an empty gameobject and dragged that game object to the OnClick editor but still my function of "Pause" won't show up even if I already have it set to public. Please help

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class uiManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public void Pause() {

        if (Time.timeScale == 1) {
            Time.timeScale == 0;
        }
        else if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
            Time.timeScale == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, you have an error in your `uiManager` script.  The function will not appear in the inspector until you resolve this error.

The problem is in your if/else statement.  You are trying to use `==` to assign a value to `Time.timeScale`. You should use the assignment operator, `=`, as seen below.

```
if (Time.timeScale == 1) 
{
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}
else if (Time.timeScale == 0)
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

Once you make this correction, save the script.  Then open Unity and press ctrl+s to save it.  This will force the editor to update the list of functions available for OnClick().